# DotNetNuke login page is broken after migration to new server

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have recently finished a DNN site and am getting ready to migrate it to the production environment. However, in the new environment the /login.aspx page is broken. It displays the correct fields but when i fill them in and try to log in nothing happens. On the network section of inspect element I can see an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. Any thoughts? I have tried EVERYTHING to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post more of the error message?  Maybe go to /Portals/_default/Logs and see if you can find the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: How did you migrate the site to production?

Comment: I transfered the dotnetnuke entire folder to the new location and restored a backup of my database on the new environment. Only change worth mentioning is I used SQL server authentication on my dev environment and the new one is under windows authentication. All the necessary config changes have been addressed, though. Otherwise the site itself wouldn´t even show up.